# Enter date into function without quotes, return date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I'm trying to write a function of this form:

```
Function cont(requestdate As Date)
    cont = requestdate
End Function
```

Unfortunately, when I enter `=cont(12/12/2012)` into a cell, I do not get my date back. I get a very small number, which I think equals 12 divided by 12 divided by 2012.  How can I get this to give me back the date? I do not want the user to have to enter `=cont("12/12/2012")`.

I've attempted to google for an answer, unfortunately, I have not found anything helpful. Please let me know if my vocabulary is correct.

Let's say my user pulled a report with 3 columns, a, b and c. a has beginning of quarter balances, b has end of quarter balances and c has a first and last name. I want my user to put in column d: `=cont(a1,b1,c1,12/12/2012)` and make it create something like:

```
BOQ IS 1200, EOQ IS 1300, NAME IS EDDARD STARK, DATE IS 12/12/2012
```

So we could load this into a database.  I apologize for the lack of info the first time around. To be honest, this function wouldn't save me a ton of time. I'm just trying to learn VBA, and thought this would be a good exercise... Then I got stuck.

Comment: Sorry, Excel won't work that way. It will automatically do the math for you and convert it to a double.

Comment: replace `=cont(12/12/2012)` to `=cont(Date(2012,12,12))` or `=cont(DateValue("12/12/2012"))`

Comment: @simoco not very easy to generalize that for use in a UDF, though...

Comment: @DavidZemens, you're right, I've didn't read the title and lost main purpose of this udf:)

Comment: I think the answer is per @sous2817, Excel will automatically do the math in that case unless you specify it as a string, with quotes.

Comment: Btw, what is the point of this UDF? If you put in cell `12/12/2012` doesn't it do what you want (return date)?

Comment: As Simoco mentioned, this UDF (in itself) is redundant. Can you post what context it will be used in? There may well be another solution

Comment: To respond to your meta question, you could "up" the responses and comments that are *helpful*, even if they don't directly solve the problem (you can still have learned something from them, etc.)

Comment: Rather than accepting the full MM/DD/YYYY, your function could accept month, day, and year as *three* separate arguments.  Then it is fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what you are really trying to accomplish.

```
        Function cont(requestdate As String) As String
            cont = Format(Replace(requestdate, ".", "/"), "'mm_dd_YYYY")
        End Function
```

This code will take a string that Excel does not recognize as a number e.g. 12.12.12 and formats it (about the only useful thing I can think of for this UDF) and return it as a string (that is not a number or date) to a cell that is formatted as text.

You can get as fancy as you like in processing the string entered and formatting the string returned - just that BOTH can never be a number or a date (or anything else Excel recognizes.)

Comment: Thank you. This gives me the same problem, however.  When I use your code, =cont(12/12/2012) gives 0/000497017 and so on.  12/12/2012=1/2012=0.000497017. Your code switches the . with a /, but the problem remains 12/12/2012 get stored as a double and not a string.

Comment: @user3613469 *You can get as fancy as you like in processing the string entered and formatting the string returned - just that BOTH can never be a number or a date (or anything else Excel recognizes.)*  When you enter "12/12/2012", this is something that Excel recognizes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do *exactly* what you're trying to do.  I will try to explain why.

You might think that because your function requires a Date argument, that this somehow forces or should force that `12/12/2012` to be treated as a Date.  And it is treated as a Date — but only **after** it's evaluated (only if the evaluated expression cannot be interpreted as a Date, then you will get an error).

**Why does Excel evaluate this *before* the function receives it?**

Without requiring string qualifiers, how could the application possibly know what *type* of data you intended, or whether you intended for that to be *evaluated*?  It could not possibly know, so there would be chaos.

Perhaps this is best illustrated by example.  Using your function:

`=Cont(1/1/0000)` should raise an error.

Or consider a very simple formula:

`=1/2`

Should this formula return `.5` (double) or `January 2` (date) or should it return `"1/2"` (string literal)?  Ultimately, it has to do one of these, and do that one thing consistently, and the one thing that Excel will do in this case is to evaluate the expression.

**TL;DR**

Your problem is that unqualified expression will be *evaluated* before being passed, and this is done to avoid confusion or ambiguity (per examples).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method for allowing quick date entry into a User Defined Function without wrapping the date in quotes:

```
Function cont(requestdate As Double) As Date

    cont = CDate((Mid(Application.Caller.Formula, 7, 10)))

End Function
```

The UDF call lines up with the OP's initial request:

```
=cont(12/12/2012)
```

I believe that this method would adapt just fine for the OP's more complex ask, but suggest moving the date to the beginning of the call:

```
=cont(12/12/2012,a1,b1,c1)
```

I fully expect that this method can be optimized for both speed and flexibility.  Working on a project now that might require me to further dig into the speed piece, but it suits my needs in the meantime.  Will update if anything useful turns up.

**Brief Explanation**

- [Application.Caller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns a Range containing the cell that called the UDF.  (See Caveat #2)
- [Mid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns part of a string (the formula from the range that called the UDF in this case) starting at the specified character count (7) of the specified length (10).
- [CDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) may not actually be necessary, but forces the value into date format if possible.

**Caveats**

1. This does require use of the full `dd/mm/yyyy` (1/1/2012 would fail) but pleasantly still works with my preferred `yyyy/mm/dd` format as well as covering *some* other delimiters.  `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd+mm+yyyy` would work, but `dd.mm.yyyy` will not because excel does not recognize it as a valid number.
2. Additional work would be necessary for this to function as part of a multi-cell array formula because Application.Caller returns a range containing all of the associated cells in that case.
3. There is no error handling, and `=cont(123)` or `=cont(derp)` (basically anything not dd/mm/yyy) will naturally fail.

**Disclaimers**

*A quick note to the folks who are questioning the wisdom of a UDF here:  I've got a big grid of items and their associated tasks.  With no arguments, my UDF calculates due dates based on a number of item and task parameters.  When the optional date is included, the UDF returns a delta between the actual date and what was calculated.  I use this delta to monitor and calibrate my calculated due dates.*

*All of this can absolutely be performed without the UDF, but bulk entry would be considerably more challenging to say the least.*

*Removing the need for quotes sets my data entry up such that loading `=cont(` into the clipboard allows my left hand to F2/ctrl-v/tab while my right hand furiously enters dates on the numpad without need to frequently (and awkwardly) shift left-hand position for a shift+'.*